# convert array of objects variable to enum using model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, enums

i want to convert this variable to enum:

```
  colors: Array<object> = [
    { name:"bob1", engValue: 'RED' },
    { name:"bob2", engValue: 'GREEN' },
    { name:"bob3", engValue: 'YELLOW' }
  ];
```

I want to create a model and inject it into my component .. 
what is the best way i can do that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "create a model"? "Inject" it?

Comment: i mean to declare a enum in file, and use it in my component

Comment: Just `import` it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you expect to export and import it? If yes for example you want to place `colors` in the file `a.ts` and take it in `b.ts`

then you can write in a.ts

```
export const color = [
    { name:"bob1", engValue: 'RED' },
    { name:"bob2", engValue: 'GREEN' },
    { name:"bob3", engValue: 'YELLOW' }
];
```

and in the `b.ts`

`import { colors } from 'a'`

Then you can use it anywhere in `b.ts`

Sorry if that is not what you want

Answer (score 0):

Enums don't exist in JS.

In TS, they're convrted to objects.

use `reduce` :

```js
const colorsArray = [
    { name:"bob1", engValue: 'RED' },
    { name:"bob2", engValue: 'GREEN' },
    { name:"bob3", engValue: 'YELLOW' }
];

const colorsObject = colorsArray.reduce((p, n) => ({ ...p, [n.name]: n.engValue }), {});

console.log(colorsObject);
```